# Windows wakes up laptop without any reason

Tags: windows, laptop, sleep

I am tired fighting with this problem. So I put my computer to sleep when I go to bed, sometimes by pressing the power button, which is configured to put the computer to sleep, sometimes it goes to sleep due to the inactivity. Then at some point, my computer wakes up during the night and coolers go super loud at maximum rpm and it can last for hours until i wake up to kill it. Moreover the computer does not respond - black screen, the only way to stop it is to long press power button it.

Event Viewer does not show any source under power-troubleshooter filter.

Last several entries in the event viewer are as follows:

```
08/06/2020 00:59:13
The system is entering sleep.

Sleep Reason: System Idle

08/06/2020 00:59:15
The system has resumed from sleep.

08/06/2020 03:59:14
The system time has changed to ‎2020‎-‎06‎-‎08T01:59:14.500000000Z from ‎2020‎-‎06‎-‎07T22:59:15.828322700Z.

Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.
Process: '' (PID 4).

08/06/2020 03:59:14
Firmware S3 times. ResumeCount: 2, FullResume: 904, AverageResume: 911

08/06/2020 03:59:14
Firmware S3 times. SuspendStart: 14305361, SuspendEnd: 14305417

08/06/2020 03:59:16
7025 - Dump after return from D3 before cmd

08/06/2020 03:59:17
7021 - Connection telemetry fields and analysis usage

08/06/2020 03:59:17
Windows cannot store Bluetooth authentication codes (link keys) on the local adapter. Bluetooth keyboards might not work in the system BIOS during start-up.
```

So at 00:59:13 the laptop went to sleep, but the next entry says it woke up, however I did not hear it. Around 4 am I woke up to a loud noise of maximum rpm of the coolers and killed the pc with the power button.

In the advanced power plan options, the wake up timers are set to disabled both for on battery and plugged in states. LAN adapter is not allowed to wake up the computer from sleep in the device manager. In the security and maintenance -> automatic maintenance the check box to wake up the computer is toggled off. The time to run the maintenance tasks is set at 13:00. Also I have checked the task scheduler, there are no scheduled tasks with the "wake up the computer to run this task" checkbox toggled on. Malware checked. Any other ideas? Let me know if you need some specific logs, laptop specs etc.

Comment: It is likely windows Update that starts the laptop. Normally you would want to check the waketimer. To check that, run `powercfg /lastwake` the moment you are back in windows again.

Comment: @LPChip it gives me 0, because the only way I leave this freeze is by rebooting the laptop.